# Group by Similar sounding names

Tags: c#, sql

We have a database of contributors. The contributor information is imported from multiple sources. Each contribute several times and enter their names each time. Some contributors misspell their names. The requirement is to find out the total contributions by each contributor. We tried SQL Soundex and Metaphone 3. Soundex is not accurate and Metaphone 3 is too time consuming. Are there any better approaches to solve this problem?

Examples:

**Sql Soundex**

```
select soundex('Opacinch') returns O125
select soundex('Opancinch') returns O152
```

**Metaphone 3**

Metaphone 3 uses ranking algorithm. each record should be compared against all the records and this results in too many groups. All the records below will be treated same if we use rank 2

```
Chandaprakash
Chandaprakas
Chandapraka
Chandaprak
Chandapra
Chandapr
Chandap
Chanda
Chand
Chan
Cha
Ch
C
```

Comment: Yes - change the table design. Sounds horrible.

Comment: How do you know `Vivk` and `Vivek` are the same contributor? Follow @juergend advice.

Comment: If you don't specify what exactly you mean by "not accurate" (show input and expected and actual matches) and "too time consuming" (mention benchmarks), we can't help you. As currently stated, this question is to be interpreted as _"throw your favorite fulltext search algorithm at me and I'll figure out if it fulfills my undisclosed requirements"_, which is not how this site works.

Comment: *Each contributor enters their name each time* - NOOOOO!

Comment: @juergen. The Contributors information are imported from multiple sources.

Comment: @tima the goal is to produce a report with similar sounding names and the audit team will get more information.

Comment: @CodeCaster i have edited the question to provide examples

Comment: Metaphone tries to find similar words phonetically. That is different to your problem.  Most people probably misspell one or two letters. Maybe you could get a list of all the different names, uppercase them, sum the ASCII values of each letter and then group by the total. This is a simple "clustering" technique that could work depending on how many contributors there are and how different are their names. You could improve the calculation of the value for each name if necessary, for instance: give more weight to the first letter since it's rare that people mispell it.

Comment: @ednincer Thank you for the Suggestion. This sounds interesting. will try this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Populate a DropDownList from your "names" table. this way every will be able to only select his name and will not be allowed to enter different spellings.

Comment: the users are not using my application to populate. They submit excel file with this information.